# Google Inapp Billing causes UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION after updating Android Studio and Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, in-app-billing

I have a project which uses Google's Inapp Billing Service and the IABHelper classes. And everything worked just fine until I updated Android Studio to it's latest "stable" release and Gradle from 0.8.x to 1.0.x .

I followed the [Migrating Gradle to 1.0.0 steps](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0). But unfortunately I get the following error for dexDebug:
Error Code 1; UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext.

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Programmierung\Android_Studio\Aviation\AviationWeather\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug C:\Programmierung\Android_Studio\Aviation\AviationWeather\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug C:\Programmierung\Android_Studio\Aviation\AviationWeather\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-d2173d36e782fa1d3f28e5e6281942ff95c70054.jar C:\Programmierung\Android_Studio\Aviation\AviationWeather\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-6fc46c00ee854d5ca04c7a8678700fa00a807727.jar C:\Programmierung\Android_Studio\Aviation\AviationWeather\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-583108ab433986d269f15fc874476a6a41305753.jar C:\Programmierung\Android_Studio\Aviation\AviationWeather\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-ddf1e2aa24f08302c35d4c53fd9a54e9d3e92c3b.jar C:\Programmierung\Android_Studio\Aviation\AviationWeather\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\StartAppInApp-2.4.11-6ad73d6077f6fe9aae60a40cb9dad0f7ce3f2b17.jar C:\Programmierung\Android_Studio\Aviation\AviationWeather\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-27d7f4d4f4a892505176f27373375f50da12ca15.jar C:\Programmierung\Android_Studio\Aviation\AviationWeather\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\libGoogleAnalyticsServices-0f3d24de5fad89dd5a88c6c233a890b5f2a4b117.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:

    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext
        at com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext.withContext(ExceptionWithContext.java:45)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:371)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:139)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:94)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:682)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.ConcreteMethod.<init>(ConcreteMethod.java:87)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.ConcreteMethod.<init>(ConcreteMethod.java:75)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:273)
        ... 22 more
    ...while processing <init> (Lcom/mytowntonight/aviationweather/MainActivity;)V
    ...while processing com/mytowntonight/aviationweather/MainActivity$1.class

    1 error; aborting
```

I tried updating the build tools - no success.

I finally found a way to compile it again, by commenting out the following code snippet:

```
IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener IABListener = new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                    if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                        // There was a problem, setting up billing
                        Log.d("Avia: Billing", "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
                    }

                    // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
                    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true,
                        new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) {
                                if (result.isFailure())
                                    return;

                                // handle Purchase
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            };
```

But this code is basically a copy from Google's Inapp Billing Tutorials and it compiled just fine until the Gradle / Android Studio update.
FYI: IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener is a public interface.

Any ideas, what the problem is?
Thank you!

Comment: First of all, what version of gradle are you using?  Can you share the **build.gradle** file with us?  Are you using multidex in your project, since your build error contains a dex exception.  And your exception is coming from Google Analytics library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was finally resolved by updating Googles In App Billing helper classes to the latest version. They are part of the billing Demo / Example and have been changed after I first implemented billing.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem a lot of times. I don't know what is the root case of this issue but the easiest solution on Linux is to restart computer or logout then login once again. Looks like this problem is related either to some kind of cache if the restart/re-login helps.

You may also try to clean the build, it may help sometimes but not always. Using terminal:

```
gradlew clean
```

Comment: I am using Windows 7. Unfortunately, rebooting and cleaning the build do not solve the problem. The error message stays the same.

Comment: It may be a bug in build tools. You should report it here: b.android.com I won't delete the answer because it may help somebody with Linux OS.